# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<DESTROYED> but was:<RESUMED>

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have an activity with a `Button` in it. On clicking the button, am calling `finish()`. The problem is, when I am writing an instrumentation test to check if the activity destroyed, I am getting

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<DESTROYED> but was:<RESUMED>

My questions are

- Why the state is still `RESUMED` even after `finish()` got called?
- Isn't it the right method to check the activity state?

Here's my activity

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.b_kill_me).setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my test

**MainActivityTest.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    fun killMe() {
        val mainActivity = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        onView(withId(R.id.b_kill_me)).perform(click())
        assertEquals(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED, mainActivity.state)
    }
}
```

Here's the complete source code : [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hisc0GVnzjzAsAQqvOIEwnAr2JuFAsJq/view?usp=sharing)